# Clarification of : M is cyclic as an abelian group if and only if it is cyclic as a Z-module.

Tags: linear-algebra

My linear algebra notes state that a  module $M$ over arbitrary commutative ring $A$ is cyclic as an abelian group $ \iff $ it is cyclic as a $\Bbb Z$-module.

I am unsure what this first statement means : "if M is cyclic as an abelian group". Does M not always contain an abelian group? Is the author saying that every element in M can be generated as a combination of of $(u_1,...,u_2) \in M$?

Comment: A $\mathbb Z$-module is *exactly* the same as an abelian group.

Comment: @PedroTamaroff so from that it follows that if an abelian group M is cylic (in terms of group theory), then a module  M over ring $\Bbb Z$ is also cylic (in terms of modules).

Comment: That is right. ${}$